# Adding ListView Dynamically Wont Render jQuery Mobile CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am adding a listview with list items to a jQuery mobile collapsible grid. Here is my Default.js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var appNames = getApprovalNames(phone, pin);

    for (var i = 0; i < appNames.length; i++) {

        var header = '<h3>' + appNames[i].Name + '</h3>';

        var ulHeader = '<ul data-role="listview" id="myAppsSectionGridTable">';

        var approvals = getApprovalInformation(phone, pin, appNames[i].Name);

        var listArray = new Array();


        for (var j; j < approvals.length; j++) {

            var link = '<li><a href="' + 'NickData' + '"' + '><img src="';
            var detailHeader = '" alt="" class="ui-li-icon"/>' + '<h3>' + 'NickData' + '</h3>';
            var detail = '<p>' + 'NickData' + '</p>' + '</a>' + '</li>';

            var list_item = link + detailHeader + detail;

            listArray.push(list_item);

        }

     var entire_list = null;

     for (var y in listArray) {

        entire_list = entire_list + listArray[y];

    }

    $('#accMain').append(header + ulHeader + entire_list + '</ul>');

    }   

});
```

This code displays the data on the screen but with no jQuery mobile css anywhere on the screen. Also when I look at it in the source, I do not see my newly created markup in there. Am I adding this in the wrong event or something? If I just hardcode the markup in the page everything works fine. Its something to do with dynamically adding jQuery mobile markup.

```
<asp:Content ID="HContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

<script src="Js/Pages/Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="THContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server">
    <h1>
        Applications</h1>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <div id="accMain" data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed="false">

 </div>

</asp:Content>
```

This master page body for this is..

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the [listview](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) method

```
$('#mylist').listview()
```

If you are just adding content to an existing listview then call the `refresh` method

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Sometime you may need to call it in your `pageshow` event, something like the following

```
 $('#myPage').on('pageshow', function() {
     try 
    {
       $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
    } catch (e) {
     $('#mylist').listview();
    }
});
```

If you are adding multiple widgets/items that need to be enhanced then you can try triggering the create event

```
$('#myPage').trigger('create');
```

Comment: do I fire the pageshow event after the document ready for the page?

Comment: JQM fires the [pageshow](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html) `event`, the example I gave is just to bind to it, as long as your page is already in the `DOM` you can bind to it before you add your list.

Comment: the collapsiblelist does not render either. Do I have to somehow refresh that too??

Comment: If you have different items that need to be enhanced by JQM, try triggering the `create` method after you add them to your page like  `$('#myPage').trigger('create');` that should tell JQM to enhance everything on the page.

Comment: I tried the refresh but am getting the same result,data there but markup not rendering properly

Comment: Did you try triggering the `create event`?

Comment: I only have one "page" div for all my pages found in my master page with no id. Is this not correct? I am not sure how I am going to create an id for individual pages to implement your trigger method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15913/discussion-between-jack-and-nick-lamarca)

Comment: I fire `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pageshow` in order to make the css updated seamlessly.